# Does order matter in database composite primary keys?

Tags: sql, database

I recently came up with the following question: is order important in database primary keys?

i.e. If I have a R(a,b,c,d,e) relation and I take (a,b) as a composite primary key, is (b,a) consider the same primary key or not?

As a follow up: If R(a,b,c,d,e) is a relation and (a,b,c) is a primary key, are (a,b,c,d,e) and (a,b,c,e,d) considered to be the same or different superkeys?

Comment: So if (a,b) is a key then (d,a,b) and (a,b,d) are two different superkeys

Comment: If (a,b,c,d,e) uniquely identifies a row than (a,b,c,e,d) obviously does as well. What are you trying to figure out by differentiating them?

Comment: How many superkeys occur from (a,b,c) primary key? Is it simple counting or there is a formula to do that? I guess combinatorics?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your goal. If you need to only enforce uniqueness the order doesn't matter so the key `(a, b)` will have the same effect of `(b, a)`.

You won't get the same results if you want to use the indices that the key will be built on, because `(a, b)` will allow you sort on `a` both ascending and descending and only after that sort on `b` ascending, while if you want to sort on `b` then you won't be able to use the index at all.

Answer (score 0):

Keys in relational algebra and in relational databases are sets of attributes / columns. A set has no inherent order.

This said, the key `(a,b)` is the same as the key `(b,a)`, because they contain the same elements.

As to superkeys: Yes, that's just combinatorics. As the primary key is the minimal superkey, you can add just any attribut or set of attributes to get another superkey: `(a,b,c)`, `(a,b,d)`, `(a,b,c,d)`.

As to databases: Unique keys are important to identify a row in a table. Hence almost always a table will have a unique primary key. Sometimes you decide to give a table another, secondary, unique key. This is especially the case when you add technical keys.

An example: A country may be uniquely identified by its name, but it's also uniquely identified by its ISO code, and you still may rather want to work with a technical numeric ID issued by your DBMS. You would make all these unique keys, and as they are all minimal superkeys, you'd just decide for one to be primary.

As to the non-minimal superkeys: they are just a theoretical construct; nothing you'd have to even know about when working with a database.